# How do I get plt.show() to show plots from the terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

I am taking what has worked in a jupyter notebook and placing in a .py file to be ran from the terminal.  When I run this from the terminal, my plot does not show.  I am in a linux GCP environment.  Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def moving_average(d, extra_periods=1, n=3):
    #historical period length
    cols = len(d)
    
    #append null values to account for future forecast
    d = np.append(d, [np.nan]*extra_periods)
    # define a forecast array
    f = np.full(cols+extra_periods, np.nan)
    
    #create all the t+1 forecast until end of historical period
    for t in range(n, cols):
        f[t] = np.mean(d[t-n:t])
        
    #forecast all the extra periods
    f[t+1:]=np.mean(d[t-n+1:t+1])
    
    #return dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Demand':d, 'Forecast':f, 'Error':d-f})
    
    return df

d = [28,19,18,13,19,16,19,18,13,16,16,11,18,15,13,15,13,11,13,10,12]
df = moving_average(d, extra_periods=4,n=3)

df[['Demand','Forecast']].plot()
plt.show()
```

How can I get this and future plots to show in the terminal environment?

Comment: Try plt.show(block=True) to explicitly block code after display.

Comment: Often when working in the terminal on a remote machine that is headless, you'll want to save the plot as an image you can download and use elsewhere later. To do that here, replace `plt.show()` with `plt.savefig('my_plot.png')`, see [here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-save-a-plot-to-a-file-using-matplotlib/) for a good summary of additional options. If you are on a local machine you can use that too and then just view the image as you would any image on your machine.